# What purpose does the tag [stackoverflowerror] serve?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags

The [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/stackoverflow) tag is already available for questions related to a stack overflow. Its description suggests a Java specificity, but there is really nothing special about stack overflows in Java that would set them apart from the same error in other languages, and a question can always be tagged [java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java) and [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/stackoverflow).

I find it rather strange to see a post like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23574133/ternary-search-tree-exception-in-thread-main-java-lang-stackoverflowerror#23574133) tagged both [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/stackoverflow) and [stackoverflowerror](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/stackoverflowerror). If there is something particular about [stackoverflowerror](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/stackoverflowerror), it may be useful to make it clear on the tag description.

Comment: +1. I guess these might need merging indeed.

Comment: Okay, so... what now ?

Answer (score 6):

This is kind of [status-completed] as the [stackoverflowerror](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/stackoverflowerror) is a synonym of [stack-overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/stack-overflow):

[image: synonyms of stack-overflow]

It seems the [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/stackoverflow) got renamed to [stack-overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/stack-overflow) but I can't find the meta post on that. The question [Rename the [stackoverflow] tag for disambiguation](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/268822/rename-the-stackoverflow-tag-for-disambiguation) was the closest I could find but it's answers and voting clearly disagree with that proposal.