# Rename the [stackoverflow] tag for disambiguation

Tags: discussion, status-declined, retag-request

Can we rename [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/stackoverflow) to [stack-overflow-exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/stack-overflow-exception)? It would clarify the intent of the tag and prevent confusion.

The tag summary also indicates that such confusion is common:

> A stack overflow occurs when too much memory is used on the call stack. NOTE: Do not use this tag to refer to the Stack Overflow website. If you have a question regarding the site, please go to https://meta.stackoverflow.com

In reply to some of the answers, I am OK with any of the possible variations, including but not limited to:

- [stack-overflow-condition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/stack-overflow-condition)
- [stack-overflow-error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/stack-overflow-error)

I am just looking for an unambiguous tag that differentiates between the error and the website. Here are spme *current* examples of misuse:

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25325247/stackoverflow-the-accounts-deletion-system
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25318547/why-is-logging-into-stackoverflow-and-stackexchange-so-painful-with-firefox
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25281244/programming-stackoverflow-com
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25277041/which-font-does-academia-stack-exchange-use
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25204964/qa-etiquette-on-stackoverflow
- ...

Half of the 1st page of the tag (sorted by newest) is related to the SO site, not the error/condition/exception.

Comment: Can we then ban the tag from being recreated?  I can't think of any question that would fit that tag that doesn't belong on meta.

Comment: Can you show some examples of where this tag has been abused/confusing for many people?

Comment: It's a useful filter for messages that ought to be migrated to Meta. A similar scenario would be having a tag [tag:spam] *and all spammers would use it*.

Comment: How about [stack-overflow], that would at least indicate that it's not for stackoverflow but for a stack overlow (if you know what i mean)

Answer (score 33):

I'm going to disagree here. [stack-overflow-exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/stack-overflow-exception) is actually quite language specific. Other languages don't throw exceptions when a stack overflow occurs, see: C, C++, etc. Some other languages don't have exceptions at all. I think the [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/stackoverflow) tag is fine as-is. There's no need to add a language specific connotation to it. When someone says 'stack overflow' in the context of programming they should know what it is, without having to worry if an exception is thrown or not. If users are confusing the tag to mean the site, then that is a user problem not a tag problem IMO.

Comment: That's not really true. For example, Windows throws a structured exception on stack overflow, and Linux has a signal for it that you could describe that way.

Comment: @Puppy: Not all signals are not exceptions. Granted, the one you typically get for a SO is an exception signal. But that's an exception signal, still not an exception!

Comment: How about [tag:stack-overflow-condition] or something similar then? As long as it is unambiguous, I'm fine with it.

Comment: Take a look at my edits for clarifications and current examples.

Answer (score 12):

No. A stack overflow is one thing; an exception thrown due to a stack overflow is another, and that's not even the universal response of a computer to such a scenario.

There is no ambiguity with Stack Overflow the site, because there are no Stack Overflow questions on Stack Overflow, as the tag wiki makes clear.

The tag is fine as-is.

Comment: Take a look at my edits for clarifications and current examples.

Comment: @metacubed: Take a look at my edit.

Comment: Take a look at the tag - "there are no Stack Overflow questions on Stack Overflow" is theoretically correct, just not in practice. The point it to _prevent_ this misuse.

Comment: @metacubed: The solution is to edit the questions, not ruin the tag.

Answer (score 0):

"error" might be better than "exception" to stop some idiots pedanting about whether or not a Linux signal qualifies. But in general, differentiating between "The error" and "The website" seems great to me.

Comment: I'm still going to pedant between the stack overflow and the error that results, I'm afraid.